# Gym management software

Tags: web-apps, project-management, calendar, scheduling, reservation

I am not able to find any good (not so costly) software for managing a gym.

It is like managing a club.

The functionality may/should include:

- Facility scheduling
- Membership management
- Events
- Staff management
- SMS/email scheduling for customers
- Sales reports
- Front desk
- Task reminders
- Manage staff & organize events

Comment: What does the software have to do? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: [15 Best Gym Management Software Tools for Gym Owners in 2021](https://allthatsaas.com/roundup/best-gym-management-software/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Regpack](http://www.regpacks.com/membership/). They don't offer a gym specific product but essentially their software adapts to any kind of business. Their membership management product would work to allow you to schedule the facility and other events, manage your members, send out automated and personalized emails, give you tons of reports on members, finances, etc, allow members to pay membership fees online, invoices, etc